# How to redirect_to "nothing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I'm working with [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable).

So my routes look like this:

```
  resources :git do
    member do
      get :like
      get :unlike
    end
  end
```

I didn't create the files `like.html.erb` & `unlike.html.erb` cause i don't need the View.

my Like Action:

```
  def like
    @git = Git.find(params[:id])
    @git.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

My Problem is, the `Git`  Index file has a looooong list and if anyone "Likes" it the page is refreshed from the redirection and the user has lost his scroll position.

How can i block out the redirection ? To just do **nothing** ?

My View:

```
<span><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i> <%= link_to "Like", like_git_path(git) %></span>
<div class="b2-widget-count" style="display: inline-block">
  <i></i><u></u><div class="b2-widget-val"><%= git.likes.size %></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to send `head :no_content` or `render nothing: true`. I recommend first one due to problems with jquery on the second.

```
  def like
    @git = Git.find(params[:id])
    @git.liked_by current_user
    render text: @git.likes.size
  end
```

Change your routes to POST.

Then, make sure you have `gem jquery-rails` line in the Gemfile.

Add this two lines to top of your `application.js` file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Add this lines to bottom of `application.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.like-button, .unlike-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    url = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');
    $.post(url).done(function(data){
      $(e.currentTarget).closest('.b2-widget-val').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Add corresponding classes (`like-button, unlike-button`) to your `link_to` helpers.

Comment: Could you write how that goes in to the controller action please ?

Comment: I think this breaks something.. The like action is not working anymore. Is there any other way ?

Comment: I forgot, you will need to handle it by AJAX request. Do you use jQuery? Please post your view code too.

Comment: I'm a little noob on JS things, if you could help me out with it, it would be cool.

Comment: Thats awesome, Could you join me in chat ? -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48792/like-button-ajax-jquery

Answer (score 0):

How does the user get into these functions? Do they click a button? If so, check out `button_to`. Also, this may be better suited as a POST action.

Comment: Yes they click it. I've tried that, but it gives me the same Routing error: No route matches [POST] "/messages/18/like"

Comment: Instead of the nested routes, you could have a route like `post 'member/:id/like', to: 'members#like`. Or something along those lines.

Comment: From what i recently learned, i will need an Ajax, jQuery solution to handle this properly !